# How to install a private testnet?

Tags: testnet, nxt

I'm looking to make my own NxT testnet for developpement purpose but couldn't find a way to do it.

I'm currently using the normal " testnet " but couldn't find the way to properly configure the nxt-default.propreties so that i could make local testnet.

Do you guys have any pointers ? or config files ? Will i be able to use my testnet on the same computer or should it be run on a server the same way a public node would ? What about setting up the configure of the genesis block , etc ?

Hope you guys can help

Answer (score 1):

See https://nxtforum.org/testnet/public-testnet-node/ for a description how to setup a testnet node.

Comment: Yes i saw that already but it's a public node.

Comment: All you need to do is install NXT on your local workstation. Set the flag  nxt.isTestnet=true as explained in the forum, start your node and let it download the testnet blockchain.

Comment: Yes but this will connect to a public node.I want a private node on my own server. With my own blockchain.